# How do I stop my bot from spamming discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a setup command. Everything works but the command spams instead of sending it once

```py
@kara.command()
async def setup(ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await guild.create_role(name=silenced, permissions = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False), reason=f"Invoked by {ctx.author}")
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Silenced")
        for chan in guild.channels:
            await chan.set_permissions(silenced, send_messages=False)
            setup=discord.Embed(title="Kara's setup", color=c.teal(), url=rick_roll, description="If the setup goes wrong make sure I have the correct permissions!")
            setup.add_field(name="Silenced Role", value="Setting up my own muted role...")
            msg = await ctx.send(embed=setup)
            
            setup2=discord.Embed(title="Kara's setup", color=c.teal(), url=rick_roll, description="If the setup goes wrong make sure I have the correct permissions!")
            setup2.add_field(name="Silenced Role", value="Setting up my own muted role...")
            setup2.add_field(name="Coming Soon...", value="Currently this is all to the setup soo... yea")
            msg = await ctx.send(embed=setup)
            await asyncio.sleep(3.4)
            await msg.edit(embed=setup2)
```

It just spams the setup I've tried moving the send outside of the for but it doesn't work any help appreciated.

Comment: check whether there are more instances running.  If so, close them. also is the code inside a cog or not? provide details

Comment: it's spamming because you added `await ctx.send(embed=setup)` in the for loop. That's what you wanted

Comment: How do I remove it and have it send once

Comment: It's outside of a cog

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of options to try:

You should add a `break` under `await msg.edit(embed=setup2)`.

Another cause could be that your `on_message` event misses a `await bot.process_commands(message)`. note that this should match `async def on_message(msg):`'s indentation. Just make sure it's added at the end of the event.

The proper solution needs explaining why it is bad to use `*.send()` in a for loop.

In a for loop, the program iterates over an iterable. Be it a list in this example. If the iterable contains more than 1 item, the code within the for loop will run more than once.

The behavior you described, "spamming", is caused by an iterable having more than 1 item, specifically `ctx.guild.channels`, which contains channel objects representing the channels in a discord server.

### Solution

You should finish whatever you have to do with those channels. (i.e.) format them nicely and when you're done, it is advised to use `*.send()` outside the for loop.